# Remove rows with similar values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, row

I want to remove all rows where Column "a" value = Column "b" value from the DataFrame like this:

```py
    a   b
1 AAA BBB
2 AAA CCC
3 AAA AAA
4 CCC CCC
5 CCC BBB
6 CCC DDD
```

Desired output:

```py
     a  b
1 AAA BBB
2 AAA CCC
3 CCC BBB
4 CCC DDD
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
In [93]: df.loc[df.a.ne(df.b)]
Out[93]:
     a    b
1  AAA  BBB
2  AAA  CCC
5  CCC  BBB
6  CCC  DDD
```

keep the rows where "a" values are *n*ot *e*qual to the "b" values.

Answer (score 2):

`df_filtered = df[df['a'] = df['b']]`

**or** if you want to drop the rows then

`df.drop(df[df['a'] = df['b']].index, inplace = True)`

Answer (score 1):

> you can try:

```
df = df[df['a'] != df['b']]
```

Answer (score -1):

you can drop the duplicates like this.

```py
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: that does something different, you can see by running that

Comment: yeah, it drops rows by other pattern

Comment: fwiw, not my downvote but i can see why

Comment: This does not exactly answers the author's question. It will drop the duplicate rows in data frame, but questions asked was to drop rows where values in both the columns are same.